# How to make each Wordpress post clickable and read the link from the title element of a post to apply it to the body of that specific post?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, ecmascript-6, clickable

I'm still quite a beginner, so please forgive me this basic (and long) question.

So I am stuck on a simple problem.
I have a Wordpress site where I have a *news page*, technically these are blog posts. These posts appear one after the other. 
Each post contains a title `<h2>` which contains a link `<a href="https://...">`.
I tried to make each post clickable, so you can click on the entire surface of a blog post, not only on the `<h2>` title. By clicking a blog post it should redirect to the same URL as the `<h2>`'s link.
I tried it with simple JavaScript the following way.

The HTML:

```
<div class="news-container">
  <div class="blog-content-wrapper">
    <div class="blog-post-container">
      <h2 class="blog-entry-title">
        <a href="https://websiteaddress.com" target="_self">A Title</a>
      </h2>
      <div class="blog-entry-text">
        <p class="blog-post-content-text">
          Lorem ipsum text.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blog-content-wrapper">
    <div class="blog-post-container">
      <h2 class="blog-entry-title">
        <a href="https://websiteaddress.com" target="_self">An Other Title</a>
      </h2>
      <div class="blog-entry-text">
        <p class="blog-post-content-text">
          Lorem ipsum text.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blog-content-wrapper">
    <div class="blog-post-container">
      <h2 class="blog-entry-title">
        <a href="https://websiteaddress.com" target="_self">Still A Title</a>
      </h2>
      <div class="blog-entry-text">
        <p class="blog-post-content-text">
          Lorem ipsum text.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 .
 .
 .
etc.
```

The JavaScript:

```
// select a post
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.blog-content-wrapper')

for (let i = 0; i < wrapper.children.length; i++) {
  let links = wrapper.children[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
//getting the link
  const link = links[0];
//getting each post's 'boxes'
  let box = wrapper.children[i]
// to click on the 'box' and open the link
  box.addEventListener('click', function () {
   window.open(link, '_self');
  });
}
```

The getElementsByTagName('a') returns a collection. If I have 6 posts normally it should iterate 6 links.
Where I stuck is to make a given post to get its own link. Let say the 2nd post should get the 2nd link. 
*(PS: I do not understand and I don't use JQuery)*


Thanks!

Comment: No, don't use jQuery. It's a library that's rarely needed anymore. Do it with plain JavaScript.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how to use this site. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing really beats proper semantic html. So your best bet should be to change the wrapper element to an 'a' tag.

However, here is the solution, along with a codepen, i came up with:

https://codepen.io/webdevjones/pen/jOYjGjr

```
//grab all the posts
const posts = document.querySelectorAll('.blog-content-wrapper')

//loop over each post, grab the link, add click event listner to .blog-content-wrapper
for(let i = 0; i < posts.length; ++i){
    //each post that we get is its own DOM, 
    //so we can call query selector again to isolate THIS blogs '<a>' tag
    const blogLinkTag = posts[i].querySelector('a')
    //extract link from href attribute
    const link = blogLinkTag.href

    //Optional: You could totally set this in css, but i didn't
    posts[i].style.cursor = 'pointer'

    //click event handler
    posts[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        //sends us to the new page
        window.location.href = link
    })
}
```